# How to insert values in table after adding new column at once?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, primary-key, insert-update

I have a mysql table. I have inserted a new column namely s_no (integer) at first position. Now I want to insert values from 1, 2, 3 at once and also want to make it primary key.

Comment: do you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

#### To make it primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (s_no);
```

*Read more at:*

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-primary-key/

#### To insert rows:

```
INSERT INTO tableName
    (a,b,c)
VALUES
    (1,2,3),
    (4,5,6),
    (7,8,9);
```

> INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows. To
> do this, include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed within
> parentheses and separated by commas.

*Read more at:*

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html